# Sliiide.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a sliding side panel to handle my navigation for the mobile version of my website using the sliiide.js plugin. (link: https://github.com/ahmedrad/sliiide ) but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
//Div button to toggle slide on 
<div id="sliiider-toggle">
     <p>Click Here</p>
</div>

//Nav div
<div class="left-menu" id="left-menu" style="visibility: hidden;">
   <ul>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
   </ul>
   <span class="slider-exit">×</span>
</div>

//Javascript
<script src="js/sliiide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var settings = {
        toggle: "#sliiider-toggle", 
        exit_selector: ".slider-exit", 
        animation_duration: "0.5s", 
        place: "left", 
        animation_curve: "cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.01, 0.57, 1.03)", 
        body_slide: true, 
        no_scroll: true, 
    };

    $(‘#left-menu’).sliiide(settings); //initialize sliiide
</script>
```

if anyone has any advice on what I'm missing, or even a better plugins to use and how to implement it, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to work" is not very specific.  What does that mean?  Do you have error messages in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gilly3 mentioned, it's not very specific.

Have you tried using quotation marks instead of a apostrophe in your last line?

Your code:

```
$(‘#left-menu’).sliiide(settings);
```

Correct written code

`$("#left-menu").sliiide(settings);` or `$('#left-menu').sliiide(settings);`

EDIT:

```
no_scroll: true, 
    };
```

Should be

```
no_scroll: true
    };
```

You don't need a comma as it is the last setting.

Comment: Using quotation marks instead of apostrophe fixed the problem! Thanks I never would have caught that haha